# How to get the value of the first key of each dictionary in a list using LOOP?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

Sample code:

```
dict1 = {"firstname":"Anna", "lastname":"Lupe", "ID":12000789}
dict2 = {"firstname":"Max", "lastname":"Mustermann", "ID":12345}

list_of_dict = [dict1, dict2]
print(list_of_dict)
```

Output:

```
[{'firstname': 'Anna', 'lastname': 'Lupe', 'ID': 12000789}, {'firstname': 'Max', 'lastname': 'Mustermann', 'ID': 12345}]
```

How can I get(print) all first names using a LOOP? Say, something like:

```
for el in list_of_dict:
    print el[0]
```

However dictionary does not support indexing...

Comment: `print el['firstname']` instead of `print el[0]` and you should be good...

Comment: Thank you! Indeed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get dict keys using dict.keys(), then convert it to a list and get first one.

```
dict1 = {"firstname": "Anna", "lastname": "Lupe", "ID": 12000789}
dict2 = {"firstname": "Max", "lastname": "Mustermann", "ID": 12345}

list_of_dict = [dict1, dict2]
print(list_of_dict)

for el in list_of_dict:
    first_key = list(el.keys())[0]
    print(el[first_key])
```